# "onchange" function never called when I load file in form

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, symfony4

I am building a form using the bootstrap CSS in my Symfony project.

The problem is that when I set up a ["File Input](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/file-input/)" field and when I actually load a file, the name of the file doesn't appear in this input.

So I tried to use this code :

```js
$('.custom-file-input').on('change', function(event) {
                    var inputFile = event.currentTarget;
                    $(inputFile).parent()
                        .find('.custom-file-label')
                        .html(inputFile.files[0].name);
                });
```

But the event "on change' is never called ( I tried to put an alert).
But it seems to work [here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-uploads/bootstrap-styling). I don't understand where is the problem ...

Comment: Please add relevant scripts and HTML to the snippet you made to make it [mcve]

Comment: Do you want that I add my twig HTML code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution wasn't to add

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But it was just to move the javascript includes in the  block instead of the end of the  !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ! Just add :

```js
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery 2.1.1 is no longer supported.  jQuery 3.4.1 is the newest version.

Comment: Oh yes I found the solution !